# What is the easiest way to merge columns with different data based on a duplicate cell?

Tags: excel, merge

Was hoping I could get some assistance with this - I'm a bit of an excel amateur.

I have a spreadsheet of customer records, each customer has their own unique customer ID, that was used on both sheets. Columns A through O is data from the first sheet, column K is the unique customer ID, and columns Q through U are what I am trying to merge. Data from the first sheet has no information in columns Q through U, whereas data from the second sheet does have data - what I want to do is:

1. If the customer ID matches between the two rows, check to see if there is data in cells Q, R, S, T, U
2. If there is data in those cells, copy the contents of those cells to the OTHER customer ID row with the same customer ID, but only IF those cells are blank, and only IF there is some data in columns L, M and N for that row.
3. Delete the duplicate row that data was pulled from

I originally tried to do this by highlighting duplicates and sorting, then copying data over, but the datasets are slightly different sizes and there may be triplicates (rather than duplicates) of unique customer IDs. Is there any easyish way to do what I am looking for? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it possible to add some mock data in the different sheets for us to use to do this?

Comment: For sure - the only problem is that the data has already been put in to one sheet and given to me (long story). I can replace all the blanks in the relevant columns with any data you wish

Comment: What I meant (and probably explained poorly) in my original post is that the two sheets have been combined already, but are still distinguishable based off of the fact that some cells are filled and some aren't filled in the Q through U range

Answer (score 0):

Don't merge the 2 sheet together. If second sheet contains information in columns Q through U and the first sheet dosen't, you can use a vlookup formula based on the unique customer id to retrieve columns Q through U and populate them in sheet 1. The vlookup will take the first match of the customer in sheet 2 based on the unique customer id.

Please place the formula below in column Q. You can then adapt the formula for columns R,S,T,U once you have gotten it working in column Q.

```
=VLOOKUP(K1,Sheet2!A:U,17,FALSE)
```

**K1** is the unique customer id

**Sheet2** is where the data is stored that you want to retrieve

**A:U** is the range of cells you which to query

**17** is the cell which you want to return (In this case , its column Q in sheet2)